# Generalized fundamental theorem of Galois theory

Tags: galois-theory

In the generalized fundamental theorem of Galois theory, theorem says there is a one-to-one correspondence between the set of all intermediate fields of extension and the set of all $\textbf{closed}$ subgroups of the Galois group $Aut_KF$. It seems to say that there can be some subgroup of the Galois group that is not closed. Is it true? If so, please give me an example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to be you're thinking of profinite groups, but then a counterexample may be hard to come up with...look here for some ideas (read below the abstract) about normal non-closed subgroups: https://www.ma.rhul.ac.uk/profinite_groups/Notes_Nikolay_Nikolov.pdf

Comment: The Galois group of a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ is the profinite group $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$, and $\mathbb{Z}$ is a non-closed subgroup of $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$.